# why this code means that all tables share a single metatable

Tags: lua, lua-table

I got a requirement that all read-only tables can share a single metatable, the code phrase answer this requirement, but i can not understand how this code phrase achieve that goal

```
local index = {}
local mt = {
  __index = function ( t, k )
    return t[index][k]
  end,

  __newindex = function ( t, k, v )
    -- body
    error("update the value is prohibited",2)
  end
}



function readonly(t)
  local proxy = {}
  proxy[index] = t
  setmetatable(proxy,mt)
  return proxy
end
```

Comment: That implementation is really really fragile, as accessing the field `index` of any "read only" table would return the actual table, breaking everything. A better aproach would be to use an [ephemeron table](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#2.5.2) to store the corresponding "real" table for every proxy object.

Comment: It seems that the very requirement "that all read-only tables can share a single metatable" has lead to a poor implementation of read-only tables, as compared to [PIL 13.4.5](https://www.lua.org/pil/13.4.5.html). It captures the wrapped table in a unique metatable so it is much simpler. (Not saying there is anything wrong with the goal of the requiremet, though.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you have provided seems to be an attempt to use a Proxy Table Pattern. It works but it is not a valid implementation of "read-only tables". That's because your proxy table holds a reference to table it is supposed to cover. It is stored in a field with key that is equal to `index`. This means one can easily edit values that should be read-only with e.g.:

```
local A = readonly {foo = 7}
print(A.foo) -- prints: 7
local _,ro = next(A)
ro.foo = 17
print(A.foo) -- prints: 17
```

How should "Proxy Table" work? In short, the whole idea is to use an empty table as a proxy between user and the read-only table. We assign a metatable with `__index` and `__newindex` metamethods to the proxy table.

- `__index` is called whenever one will try to access a field that "holds" value `nil`.
- `__newindex` is called whenever one will try to create a new field in a table.

Since our proxy table is always empty, every assignment will trigger `__newindex`:

```
local B = readonly {bar = 8}
B.foo = 7 -- non-existent in both proxy and readonly table -> calls __newindex
B.bar = 3 -- exists in readonly table but does not exist in proxy -> calls __newindex
```

For the same reason, every time a field is accessed `__index` will kick in:

```
local B = readonly {bar = 8}
print(B.foo) -- does not exist in proxy, __index is called -> prints "nil"
print(B.bar) -- does not exist in proxy, __index is called -> prints "8"
```

As for a more valid example, see below. It still has issues (e.g. table mode could be changed to make keys weak; see comments), but at least it covers read-only table.

```
local index = {}

local mt = {
  __index = function (t, k)
    return index[t][k]
  end,
  __newindex = function ()
    -- body
    error("update the value is prohibited",2)
  end,
}

function readonly (t)
  local proxy = {}
  index[proxy] = t
  setmetatable(proxy, mt)
  return proxy
end
```

In case of doubts you can refer to:

- [PIL - 13.4.4](https://www.lua.org/pil/13.4.4.html),
- [PIL - 13.4.5](https://www.lua.org/pil/13.4.5.html),
- [Lua Reference Manual - 2.4](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#2.4),
- [Proxy Based Encapsulation](http://lua-users.org/wiki/ProxyBasedEncapsulation).

Comment: `> Since our proxy table is always empty` Except the `index` field, as I mentioned in my comment under the question ;)

Comment: @DarkWiiPlayer It did not refer to the code sample but to the previous paragraph. I have mentioned the problem with sample in first paragraph and then in second part of the answer.

Comment: Oh, I must have overlooked that; sorry :P

Comment: As mentioned in my other comment though, you could set the `rotables` table to have weak keys, otherwise you will keep tables from being garbage-collected.

Comment: Yes, however spirit of this answer was to explain what design pattern code sample tries to follow (poorly, but still). Fix to the code sample was just a small addition.

Comment: @ Green **That's because your proxy table holds a reference to table it is supposed to cover. It is stored in a field with key that is equal to index. This means one can easily edit values that should be read-only.** i have the __newindex function defined, and i have set the metatable, how this happen that  one can easily edit values that should be read-only

Comment: @user3454525 `proxy[index] = t` from your sample; you can then access `t` through `proxy[index]` and modify it. Let me add an example.